# input.value in array return 0

Tags: javascript, html

i'm makeing score counter and i'm trying to display a message with the value of my winning score input (Where the player chooses how many points to play).

When I use input.value outside the array, it works fine. But when I try to use it within the array, it returns me 0.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#scoresInput");
var msgWindow = document.querySelector("#msgWindow");
var wsDisplay = document.querySelector("p span") // winning score display


input.addEventListener("change", function(){
    if(this.value <= 0){
    msg("errorMsg", 2);

    }else{
    msg("newMsg", 1);
    wsDisplay.textContent = this.value;
    }
});

var msgIndex = [
    "new game begins now you play to " + input.value + " scores",
    "you can't play to " + input.value + " scores(",
    "! player 1 is the winner!",
    "! player 2 is the winner!"
];

function msg(msgClass, i){
    msgWindow.classList.add(msgClass);
    msgWindow.textContent = msgIndex[i];
}
```

```html
    <h1><span id="p1Display">0</span> - <span id="p2Display">0</span</h1>
    <p>you play to <span>3</span></p>

<input id="scoresInput" type= "number">
<button id="p1">player1</button>
<button id="p2">player2</button>
<button id="reset">newGame</button>
<p id="msgWindow"></p>
```

//I expect the real time output of the input value but
input.value in the array always return 0.

Comment: You're setting `msgIndex` when the page first loads, not after the user enters something in the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a variable in an array value copies the value at the time you execute the assignment, it doesn't make it re-evaluate the variable each time the array is used.

You can put a placeholder in the string, and replace it in your `msg()` function.

If you need more replacements like this, you should find a template library that automates it.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#scoresInput");
var msgWindow = document.querySelector("#msgWindow");


input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (this.value <= 0) {
    msg("errorMsg", 2);

  } else {
    msg("newMsg", 1);
    //wsDisplay.textContent = this.value;
  }
});

var msgIndex = [
  "new game begins now you play to {INPUTVALUE} scores",
  "you can't play to {INPUTVALUE} scores(",
  "! player 1 is the winner!",
  "! player 2 is the winner!"
];

function msg(msgClass, i) {
  msgWindow.classList.add(msgClass);
  msgWindow.textContent = msgIndex[i].replace('{INPUTVALUE}', input.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="scoresInput" type="number">
<button id="p1">player1</button>
<button id="p2">player2</button>
<button id="reset">newGame</button>
<p id="msgWindow"></p>
```